# Match a substring with character, digits and spaces with gsub

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a string like:

```
a <- '{:name=>"krill", :priority=>2, :count=>1}, {:name=>"vit a", :priority=>2]}, {:name=>"vit-b", :priority=>2, :count=>1}, {:name=>"vit q10", :priority=>2]}'
```

I would like to parse via `str_match` the elements within ':name=>" ' and ' " '

```
krill
vit a
vit-b
vit q10
```

So far I tried:

```
str_match(a, ':name=>\\"([A-Za-z]{3})')
```

But it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is your string `a <- '{:name=>"krill", :priority=>2, :count=>1}, {:name=>"vit a", :priority=>2]}, {:name=>"vit-b", :priority=>2, :count=>1}, {:name=>"vit q10", :priority=>2]}'`?

Comment: What is your actual string?  Is it some form of JSON?  My guess is that you should not be using regex to parse it.

Comment: it is not a json unfortunately, fields may vary and it's unstructured. @Tim

Comment: edited the string. @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `stringr` and *positive lookbehind*:

```
library(stringr)
str_match_all(a, '(?<=:name=>")[^"]+')

[[1]]
     [,1]     
[1,] "krill"  
[2,] "vit a"  
[3,] "vit-b"  
[4,] "vit q10"
```

Answer (score 2):

You may extract those values with

```
> regmatches(a, gregexpr(':name=>"\\K[^"]+', a, perl=TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "krill"   "vit a"   "vit-b"   "vit q10"
```

The [`:name=>"\\K[^"]+` pattern](https://regex101.com/r/mfllS4/1) matches

- `:name=>"` - a literal substring
- `\K` - omits the substring from the match
- `[^"]+` - one or more chars other than `"`.

If you need to use `stringr` package, use `str_extract_all`:

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract_all(a, '(?<=:name=>")[^"]+')
[[1]]
[1] "krill"   "vit a"   "vit-b"   "vit q10"
```

In [`(?<=:name=>")[^"]+`](https://regex101.com/r/mfllS4/2), the `(?<=:name=>")` matches any location that is immediately preceded with `:name=>"`.

Comment: So `\K` omits everything before it from the match?

Comment: @snoram Yes, `\K` is a [match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) that clears the current match buffer.\